# Record total number of chess games by a player

Tags: history, statistics

I just read in a chess mag that Korchnoi holds the record with 5000+ documented games. I'm a bit sceptic about that - should I a) ever *electronically* document my games (currently they are just a titanic sheet heap) and b) live only remotely to his age, I probably vaporize that record. And with around 80 tournament games a year (if I'm busy) and 350 rated tournaments since national rating went from Ingo to DWZ, I'm not even the top chess enthusiast (I know a dude with a 600+ after his number).
Thus, I expect the above statement to hold for GM rated players and for well-documented game sets, but not necessarily for each and any chess player worldwide.

A quick googling gave no reliable data (and rapid or online games don't count anyway for my question) - does someone has a source for total number of games stats?

Comment: What is a "documented game"?

Comment: @Minot: Some Megabase, obviously. (Tournament books etc. count too, but first show me a game only found in some obscure tournament book... ;-)